# How to efficiently populate an array with values from different functions?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have an array `x` of length `n_x`, an array `all_par1` of length `n_par1` and a single parameter `par2`. Furthermore, two functions `func1` and `func2` that take these parameters and `x` as input.

I want to create an array with the dimensions `n_x` x `2 * n_par1`, where the first half of the columns is populated with the values from `func1` and the second half with values from `func2`.

I currently do it like this:

```
import numpy as np


def func1(x, par1):
    return x / (par1 + x)


def func2(x, par1, par2):
    return -par1 * x / ((par2 + x) ** 2)


def populate_matrix(xvec, par1_vec, par2):

    first_half = np.stack((func1(xvec, par1_i) for par1_i in par1_vec), axis=1)
    second_half = np.stack((func2(xvec, par1_i, par2) for par1_i in par1_vec), axis=1)

    return np.concatenate((first_half, second_half), axis=1)


np.random.seed(0)

all_par1 = [1., 2., 3.]
my_par2 = 5.

n_x = 2
x_variable_length = np.random.rand(n_x)
print x_variable_length

mat = populate_matrix(x_variable_length, all_par1, my_par2)
```

This gives me then e.g.

```
[[ 0.35434447  0.21532117  0.15464704 -0.01782479 -0.03564959 -0.05347438]
 [ 0.416974    0.26340313  0.19250415 -0.02189575 -0.0437915 -0.06568725]]
```

As `n_x` is 2, it has two rows, the first half of columns is generated with `func1` which is always positive, the second half with values from `func2` which are always negative.

I need to call this function a lot of times and I am wondering whether this is the most efficient way of doing it. Any ideas?

Not sure whether it is of interest but the actual dimensions are something like 300 x 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the vectored way for a 10x improvement on big arrays (100x200 in the tests) :

```
def populate_matrix_v(xvec, par1_vec, par2):
    n,m=xvec.size,par1_vec.size
    res= np.empty((n,m+m))
    res[:,:m]=func1(x_variable_length[:,None],par1_vec)
    res[:,m:]=func2(x_variable_length[:,None], par1_vec, par2) 
    return res

In [377]: %timeit matv = populate_matrix_v(x_variable_length, all_par1, my_par2)
171 µs ± 6.13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [378]: %timeit mat = populate_matrix(x_variable_length, all_par1, my_par2)
1.88 ms ± 61.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: That works fine, upvoted (I wait with acceptance for a while to see whether something else shows up...)